# Mapping Generated Offset and Size equivalent in Node?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I used the internal Blender renderer (version 2.79) and it was possible to change the size and offset of the texture mapping. Is there an equivalent in the Node editor?

[image: Image Mapping]

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use the mapping node, which has a scale and movement setting inside of it.

Comment: Ahh thank you I was able to make it work.